# PHP Redirect Check in Joomla: Need to Exclude Content Pages from being Redirected

Tags: php, redirect, joomla

I have created a function in one of my Joomla PHP files. Essentially, the function checks to see if a user's ID is found in a database. If the user's ID is not found, then it redirects to Content-A. If the user's ID is found in the database, then it redirects to Content B. In the code below, if $result returns true, then the user's ID was found.

Here it is in the current working form:

```
    else

    {

        // Get Current Users Joomla ID            
        $user =& JFactory::getUser();        

        // Search Database for Joomla Users ID

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('user_id');
        $query->from('database_table');
        $query->where('user_id = ' . $user->id);
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadResult();  

    if ($result && ((JRequest::getCmd('option') != 'com_content') || (JRequest::getCmd('view') != 'article') || (JRequest::getInt('id') != 'XXX')))

{
```

This code says if there is a $result, and the current page loaded in the browser is not content id XXX, then execute the following function.  What I need to do is also include 2 other page id's to check.  So if the user is on one of these three page IDs, then they won't be redirected.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    if ($result && ((JRequest::getCmd('option') != 'com_content') || (JRequest::getCmd('view') != 'article') || ((JRequest::getInt('id') != 'XXX') || (JRequest::getInt('id') != 'YYY') || (JRequest::getInt('id') != 'ZZZ'))))

{
```

I think I'm close, but site goes into a redirect loop when I save this code.  Can someone suggest a way to fix the syntax?  Thanks in advance for any help!

EDITS:  There are really 4 content types that need to be handled in this workflow.

Content-A = Display if the user is logged in and their user ID is not found in a database

Content-B = Display if the user is logged in and their user ID is found in a database

Content-C = Is accessed from Content-B through a Link

Content-D = Is displayed on Content A, B & C through a light box pop up (RocketTheme's RokBox)

Comment: You should add the code of the `function above` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made it a bit clean ,simple if condition will help to find the problem.

```
$articleId = (JRequest::getVar('option')==='com_content' && JRequest::getVar('view')==='article')? JRequest::getInt('id') : 0; //Get the article's ID

$dont_redirect = array('12','13','15'); //ID's of those specific articles

if($result && !in_array($articleId , $dont_redirect))
{
```

If it still doesn't work , it's probably the $result variable , what's the value of it?
Use:

```
var_dump($result);
```

before the condition.

Comment: Thanks Ofir!  This worked for two of the content ID's, but not the third.  Here's a little more background info: the content is appearing in a facebook iFrame, ported through Joomla.  Two of the three pages will fill the main iFrame, but the third content is accessed through a lightbox pop up using RocketTheme's RokBox... so it's an iframe in an iframe.  The $result variable is a user id, in this case, the var_dump showed "string (2) "id" ".

Comment: Please remined my why you need the `user's id` in the condition?

Comment: According to the result of the `var_dump` , your `result` variable isn't boolean ,it's a string - Check it out please.

Comment: Please add your last 3 comments to your question (using EDIT) and remove them.

Comment: Done.  :)  One other thing I just noticed.  If I right click on the Lightbox link for Content-D and open it in another tab, it takes a few seconds for the article to appear.  The browser URL is non-SEF first, then it redirects to SEF.  Then, if I go back to the facebook tab where the content is iFramed, the lightbox pop up will show Content-D.  But if I refresh the facebook page, the pop up shows Content-B. :/  Maybe when the lightbox is triggered by a users click, the code generated starts with a different URL, so the content ID doesn't match and the page gets redirected.  Thoughts?